# How to mount an Azure File Share on macOS Sierra?

Tags: mac-osx, azure, mount

I want to mount my File Share to a folder on my MBP called `/Users/me/mount-folder`. I've read the [Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share) documentation as well as the [Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-how-to-use-files-linux#mount-the-file-share) documentation.

I've been `https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28965714/Can-a-Mac-connect-to-an-Azure-file-share.html`, but I do not want to use the storage explorer (I need my Python scripts to access files on the File Share).

I've [tried](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d8662247-37ee-44ef-9457-9a15a42c0464/mount-an-azure-file-storage-account-from-mac?forum=windowsazuredata):

```
mount_smbfs -d 0777 -f 0777 //[storagename]:[key]@[storagename].file.core.windows.net/[sharedname]  [Mount point in Mac filesystem]
```

and I then get asked for a password, but I do not know what password it wants...
I did copy & paste my Azure file share key (exactly, including the ==), but it just tells me that the authentication has failed.

All the posts I've read seem to be old, from around 2015...

Comment: This is finally supported. Here's the official walk-through from Microsoft on how to do it:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-mac

Answer (score 3):

This should work today, as Microsoft added support for mounting Azure file shares in macOS.

You do not need to provide the key in the `mount_smbfs` command, though. You'll be prompted for it. You can save it in Keychain if you wish.

```
mount_smbfs -d 0777 -f 0777 //[storagename]@[storagename].file.core.windows.net/[sharedname]  [Mount point in Mac filesystem]
```

You can also mount a share via Finder; see [Microsoft's official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-mac) for more.

Answer (score 2):

Mounting an Azure File share from OSX is currently not supported. There may be a work around but the only officially supported Windows clients can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share) and Linux clients can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-how-to-use-files-linux#choose-a-linux-distribution-to-use).

The following is supported clients.

```
Windows Client  SMB Version Supported
Windows 7   SMB 2.1
Windows Server 2008 R2  SMB 2.1
Windows 8   SMB 3.0
Windows Server 2012 SMB 3.0
Windows Server 2012 R2  SMB 3.0
Windows 10  SMB 3.0


Ubuntu Server 14.04+
RHEL 7+
CentOS 7+
Debian 8
openSUSE 13.2+
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12
SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (Premium Image)
```

Also, you could refer to this [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217298-storage/suggestions/6864784-mount-azure-storage-on-desktop-in-mac-windows-pc).

Comment: That is just a copy & past from here (https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ede25ab3-74d9-4adb-b041-8eb0337b98e2/mac-smb-connect-to-azure-storage-file-share?forum=windowsazuredata), as well as copy & paste my two links. As I mentioned, the post is from 2015.

Comment: @pookie You could check the feedback I reply. Currently, Azure File share does not support.

Comment: That "feedback" link contains 2 links, both of which are in my post and in yours...

Comment: Yes, if Mac supports, Azure developer will post here.

Comment: It took 2 years for MS to respond to that post!

Comment: @pookie: You can consider this answer as a statement from another MS employee that this is (still) not supported 1.5 years later.

Comment: @pookie It will update when Mac is supported. Currently, Azure Fileshare has many limit.

Comment: @pookie Do you have other question about this issue?